# How to position labels at edges of Tikz figures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, labels

I have a problem with the 'sloped' option (see my example below). From `s0` to `s3` and `s3` to `s0`, the labels are too close to the edge. The `pos` option allows the user to move the label along the path, but what I want is to move it away from the edge while still keeping the label sloped according to the edge. Is it possible to do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm]

  \node[state,accepting][label=above:{\tiny{label:10}}] (q0)      {$s_0$};
  \node[state](q1) at (4,0)  {$s_1$};
  \node[state][label=right:\rotatebox{-90}{\tiny{label:20}}](q2) at (4,-3) {$s_2$};

  \node[state][label={[xshift=-0.9cm, yshift=-1cm]\tiny{label:5}}](q3) at (0,-3) {$s_3$};

  \path[->] (q0)  edge [in=150, out=120, loop, above, align=left] node {$a=0$ \\ $x:=x+1$} (q0);
  \path[->] (q0)  edge [bend right=10, align=left, below] node  {$a=1$} (q1);
  \path[->] (q1)  edge [bend right=10, align=left, above, inner sep=1pt] node  {$a=0$} (q0);
  \path[->] (q1)  edge [bend right=10, align=left, sloped] node  {$a=2$} (q2);
  \path[->] (q2)  edge [bend left=-10, sloped, align=left] node  {$a=1$} (q1);
    \path[->] (q0)  edge [bend right=10, sloped, align=left, inner sep=1pt] node  {$a=3$} (q3);
  \path[->] (q3)  edge [bend left=-10, align=left, sloped, inner sep=1pt] node  {$a=0$} (q0);    
  \path[->] (q0)  edge [bend left=10, align=left, sloped, inner sep=1pt]      node  {$a=2$} (q2);

  \path[->] (q2)  edge [bend left=10, align=left, sloped, near end]      node  {$a=0$} (q0);

 \path[->] (q1)  edge [bend left=10, align=left, sloped, near end]      node  {$a=3$} (q3);
 \path[->] (q2)  edge [bend left=10, align=left, below, inner sep=4pt]      node  {$a=3$} (q3);
  \path[->] (q1)  edge [in=30, out=60, loop, above, align=left]  node {$x=1$ \\ $x:=x+1$} (q1);

  \path[->] (q3)  edge  [bend left=10, align=left, sloped, inner sep=1pt] node  {$a=1$} (q1);
   \path[->] (q3)  edge  [bend right=-10, align=left, above, inner sep=1pt] node  {$a=2$} (q2);     

  \path[->] (q2)  edge  [in=-30,out=-60, loop, below, align=left, inner sep=1pt] node  {$a=2$ \\ $x:=x+1$} (q2);

  \path[->] (q3)  edge  [in=-150,out=-120, loop, below, align=left, inner sep=3pt] node  {$a=3$ \\ $x:=x+1$} (q3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By use `near end` you were very close to desired solution ... With `pos= ..` you can determine relative position of node on path. See MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',
    shorten > = 1pt,
node distance = 3cm and 4cm,
    el/.style = {inner sep=2pt, align=left, sloped},
every label/.append style = {font=\tiny}
                    ]
\node (q0) [state,accepting,label=left:{label:10}]  {$s_0$};
\node (q1) [state,right=of q0]                      {$s_1$};
\node (q2) [state,below=of q1,
            label=right:{label:20}]                 {$s_2$};
\node (q3) [state,below=of q0,
            label=left:{label:5}]                   {$s_3$};
\path[->] 
    (q0)  edge [in=150,out=120,loop] 
                node[el,above,rotate=-45] {$a=0$ \\ $x:=x+1$}   (q0)
    (q0)  edge [bend right=10]  node[el,below]  {$a=1$}         (q1)
    (q1)  edge [bend right=10]  node[el,above]  {$a=0$}         (q0)
    (q1)  edge [bend right=10]  node[el,below]  {$a=2$}         (q2)
    (q2)  edge [bend left=-10]  node[el,below]  {$a=1$}         (q1)
    (q0)  edge [bend right=10]  node[el,below]  {$a=3$}         (q3) 
    (q3)  edge [bend left=-10]  node[el,below]  {$a=0$}         (q0)
    (q0)  edge [bend left= 10]  node[el,above,pos=0.8] {$a=2$}  (q2)
    (q2)  edge [bend left= 10]  node[el,below,pos=0.8] {$a=0$}  (q0)
    (q1)  edge [bend left= 10]  node[el,above,pos=0.75] {$a=3$} (q3)
    (q2)  edge [bend left= 10]  node[el,below]  {$a=3$}         (q3)
    (q1)  edge [in=30, out=60,loop]  
                node[el,above,rotate=45] {$x=1$\\ $x:=x+1$}     (q1)
    (q3)  edge [bend left=10]   node[el,below,pos=0.75] {$a=1$} (q1)
    (q3)  edge [bend right=-10] node[el,above]  {$a=2$}         (q2)
    (q2)  edge [in=-30,out=-60, loop] 
                node[el,below,rotate=-45] {$a=2$ \\ $x:=x+1$}   (q2)
    (q3)  edge [in=-150,out=-120, loop] 
                node[el,below,rotate=45] {$a=3$ \\ $x:=x+1$}    (q3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I took liberty and change your MWE that it to be more concise. In this I correct all strange use of nodes options. For it I define new style as well redefine default label style. Also I exploit `positioning` library for positioning of automaton states.

**Addendum:**
An alternative, with use of TikZ library `quotes` and grouping edges according to their properties:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, positioning, quotes}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3cm and 4cm,
    el/.style = {inner sep=2pt, align=left},
every label/.append style = {font=\tiny},
every  edge/.append style = {draw, -stealth', shorten > = 1pt,
                             font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt, auto,
                             align=left, sloped},                       
                    ]
\node (q0) [state,accepting,label=left:{label:10}]  {$s_0$};
\node (q1) [state,right=of q0]                      {$s_1$};
\node (q2) [state,below=of q1,
            label=right:{label:20}]                 {$s_2$};
\node (q3) [state,below=of q0,
            label=left:{label:5}]                   {$s_3$};
    \begin{scope}[bend left=10,sloped]
\path[->]
    (q0)  edge ["$a=1$"] (q1)
    (q1)  edge ["$a=0$"] (q0)
    (q2)  edge ["$a=3$"] (q3)
    (q3)  edge ["$a=2$"] (q2);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[bend left=10,pos=0.64,sloped]
\path   (q1)  edge ["$a=2$"] (q2)
        (q2)  edge ["$a=1$"] (q1)
        (q0)  edge ["$a=3$"] (q3)
        (q3)  edge ["$a=0$"] (q0);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[bend left=10,pos=0.75,sloped]
\path   (q0)  edge ["$a=2$"] (q2)
        (q2)  edge ["$a=0$"] (q0)
        (q1)  edge ["$a=3$"] (q3)
        (q3)  edge ["$a=1$"] (q1);
    \end{scope}
\path   (q0)  edge [in=150,out=120,loop]
                    node[el,above,rotate=-45] {$a=0$ \\ $x:=x+1$}   (q0)
        (q1)  edge [in=30, out=60,loop]
                    node[el,above,rotate=45]  {$x=1$\\ $x:=x+1$}   (q1)
        (q2)  edge [in=-30,out=-60, loop]
                    node[el,below,rotate=-45] {$a=2$ \\ $x:=x+1$}   (q2)
        (q3)  edge [in=-150,out=-120, loop]
                    node[el,below,rotate=45] {$a=3$ \\ $x:=x+1$}    (q3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as with above MWE.